# how do you include w3school slideshow into reactJS component using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some javascript code that I need to migrate to reactjs, I'm using react hooks

but when I include the javascript file an error appaers

TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

My component code

```
import React from "react";
import '../utils/slider';

export default function Slider()
{
    return(
        <div className="">
            <div className="slideshow-container" onmouseenter="pauseSlides()" onmouseleave="startSlides()">
                <div className="mySlides">
                    <img className ="img-responsive" src="image1.png" style="width:100%;"></img>
                </div>

                <div className="mySlides">
                    <img className ="img-responsive" src="image2.png" style="width:100%;"></img>
                </div>

                <div className="mySlides">
                    <img className ="img-responsive" src="image3.jpg" style="width:100%;"></img>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span>
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from "./components/Slider";

function App()
{
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Slider />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

And my JavaScript code:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
var millis = 60000;

nextSlide();
var interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);

function resumeSlides()
{
    nextSlide();
}

function pauseSlides()
{
    clearInterval(interval);
}

function nextSlide()
{
    showSlide();
    slideIndex++;
}

function plusSlides(n)
{
    clearInterval(interval);
    slideIndex += n;
    nextSlide();
    interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);
}

function currentSlide(n)
{
    clearInterval(interval);
    slideIndex = n + 1;
    nextSlide();
    interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);
}

function showSlide()
{
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
        slides[i].style.display = "none";

    if (slideIndex > slides.length)
        slideIndex = 1;

    if (slideIndex < 1) 
        slideIndex = slides.length;

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) 
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

The error say it’s on line 63 (TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined)

```
  60 |      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  61 |  }
  62 | 
> 63 |  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  64 |  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  65 | }
```

Comment: it seems like `slides` is an empty array, since, you have this line ` slideIndex = slides.length;` before ` slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";` gives undefined

Comment: yes, this code is functional in html5 and vanilla JS, but in rsx not found my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is not supposed to work since you execute JavaScript code outside your React code and you want them to work together.

You should `useState` to store your `vars` and switch slides in `useEffect`.

Here is more or less the code you should aim to

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Slider() {
  // store your index and time in state
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(1);
  const [millis, setMillis] = useState(2000);
  const [interval, setIntervalValue] = useState();

  // use effect to manage your interval
  useEffect(() => {
    startSlides();
    return pauseSlides;
  }, []);

  // change slides in effect
  useEffect(() => {
    showSlide();
  }, [slideIndex]);

  function nextSlide() {
    setSlideIndex((idx) => idx + 1); // use state set function
  }

  function currentSlide(idx) {
    setSlideIndex(idx);
  }

  function pauseSlides() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  function startSlides() {
    nextSlide();
    const interval = setInterval(nextSlide, millis);
    setIntervalValue(interval);
  }

  function showSlide() {
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) slides[i].style.display = "none";

    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
      setSlideIndex(1);
    } else if (slideIndex < 1) {
      setSlideIndex(slides.length);
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      console.log(slideIndex);
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div
        className="slideshow-container"
        onMouseEnter={() => pauseSlides()}
        onMouseLeave={() => startSlides()}
      >
        <div className="mySlides">
          <img className="img-responsive" src="image1.png" alt="1"></img>
        </div>

        <div className="mySlides">
          <img className="img-responsive" src="image2.png" alt="2"></img>
        </div>

        <div className="mySlides">
          <img className="img-responsive" src="image3.jpg" alt="3"></img>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <span className="dot" onClick={() => currentSlide(0)}></span>
        <span className="dot" onClick={() => currentSlide(1)}></span>
        <span className="dot" onClick={() => currentSlide(2)}></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you run this code it should work and switch numbers where your images should go.

Again, this is not perfect code, because a lack of split and `useCallback` and `useRef` instead of document query but it works for your case and gives you a overall picture of what should be done.

Comment: Thank you very much. This code works very fine like the version of vanilla js and HTML 5, with this example I can try to convert my vanilla javascript accordion to rsx